# Creating multiindex column Pandas dataframe from existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame, with each observation on a separate row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'geo': ['US', 'US', 'US', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'CT', 'CT'], 
              'series': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b'], 
              'value': [1,2,3,7,4,3,4,12,13], 
               'date':  ['3/1', '3/2', '3/1', '3/1', '3/2', '3/1', '3/2', '3/1', '3/2']})

  date geo series  value
0  3/1  US      a      1
1  3/2  US      a      2
2  3/1  US      b      3
3  3/1  NY      a      7
4  3/2  NY      a      4
5  3/1  NY      b      3
6  3/2  NY      b      4
7  3/1  CT      a     12
8  3/2  CT      b     13
```

**What I want**: I want to re-organize the DataFrame so that the "date" variable is the index and geo & series are multiindex column variables. That is:

```
     US  US  NY  NY  CT  CT
     a   b   a   b   a   b
3/1  1   3   7   3   12  13
3/2  2  nan  4   4  nan  nan
```

**What I've tried**: I tried setting the index to date, geo, series, and then using "unstack", but it gives me a "duplicate value" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you can `stack()` and `unstack()`:

```
df.set_index(['date','geo','series'])['value'].unstack(['geo','series'])
```

Output:

```
geo      US        NY         CT      
series    a    b    a    b     a     b
date                                  
3/1     1.0  3.0  7.0  3.0  12.0   NaN
3/2     2.0  NaN  4.0  4.0   NaN  13.0
```

It gives you duplicate error because you have duplicated data on the three columns `date, geo, series`, for example:

```
date geo series value
 3/1  US      a     1     
 3/1  US      a     2
```

To confirm that, try to do:

```
df.duplicated(['date','geo','series']).any()
# should give you True
```

Depending what you want to do with the duplicates, you can use `groupby`:

```
# mean:
(df.groupby(['date','geo','series'])
   ['value'].mean()
   .unstack(['geo','series'])
)
```